# Pushing ViewController from didReceiveLocalNotification in AppDelegate.swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, notifications

I am having problem in pushing ViewController from AppDelegate when user pressed the Notification

Below is my code, but this code Crashes because the navigationController is nil

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {

    var rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController;

    let customDetailsViewController = CustomDetailsViewController();

    rootViewController?.navigationController!.pushViewController(customDetailsViewController, animated: true);
}
```

Any idea? Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your navigation controller is nil, then your rootViewController (the one with the arrow in your Storyboard) is not inside a NavigationController. Can you post a screenshot of the relevant part of your Storyboard?

**EDIT**:

As you are using [RESideController](https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu), you'll have a RootViewController not connected to anything in your Storyboard. That RootViewController conforms to ``protocol and you have some code like:

```objectivec
@implementation FASRootViewController

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.menuPreferredStatusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;

    self.scaleContentView = NO;
    self.scaleMenuView = NO;
    self.panGestureEnabled = YES;

    self.contentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"contentViewController"];
    self.rightMenuViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"rightMenuViewController"];
    self.delegate = (id<RESideMenuDelegate>)self.rightMenuViewController;
}
```

To "launch" your View controllers your need to add a identifier in the Storyboard

[image: add a identifier in the Storyboard]

Also, this View Controller should be a UINavigationController (not your first "content" view controller)

Comment: Yes, its not inside a NavigationController. my RootViewController is this https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu  How can I push my viewcontroller from AppDelegate then? Thank you

Comment: I see what you mean, i've figured it out. Thanks